# Firefox and Chrome: Caching previous pages after user logs out

Tags: browser-compatibility, caching

Is there a way to prevent browsers from doing this?

The backstory is, the application is a sharepoint 2010 app for a financial investments company. So needless to say this sort of caching issue cant be allowed. I normally work with sharepoint on IE and havent had this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably consider what kind of cache are you targeting: client-side cache only (try embedding Pragma:no-cache headers in specific pages/controls or even appending random query strings on every request - very bad for performance if you're doing it in the master page) or server-side cache - e.g. for Publishing sites use Caching Profiles. There is also the BLOB setting which could handle stuff such as file downloads, images, scripts, styles.

I would suggest a more global strategy to cover all you sides.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this article is relevant or not, are you using AD FS? This kind of reminds me of something I was reading about the other day regarding logon tokens.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147183.aspx

<"a grain of salt">
I'm really new at SharePoint... and programming in general...
<"/a grain of salt">

So I could be totally off...

Good Luck,

Dave